# Program to find combination of letters associated with phone keypad

Tags: c

So here is the question:

On a phone keypad, many of the numbers have letters associated with them. For instance, the letters A, B, and C are associated with the number 2. Write a program that accepts a number as input and prints all of the possible letter combinations associated with that number. For example, if the input is n=23, the possible letter combinations are AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, and CF.

I don't know how to solve this problem, but here is my idea, and the accompanying program. My idea is that since there are just 7 unique numbers, I would go through each number typed by the user, and if it is new, do a form of bitwise operation to record it. Therefore, if the user were to repeat that number again, there is some sort of memory.

Then after that, I would write a program to count the number of 1s and therefore, the different unique numbers entered by user.

Here is where I get stuck. I just can't seem to figure out how to 'store' the different numbers, because I don't know beforehand while writing the program how many the user would enter. And I don't really know how to generate all the combinations though I think a nested for loop could do it.

Anyway, I thought that my idea is way too complicated and should be simpler, since I'm in a beginner programming course. I have not learned arrays yet too. So any ideas on how to tackle this problem is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int input, i, j, k = 0, count_1 = 0, count_2 = 0, integer, check, monitor = 0;
   char alphabets;
   printf("Enter number as input: ");
   scanf("%d", &input);
   if ( input < 50 || input > 57 ) {
      printf("Enter number as input: ");
      scanf("%d", &input);
   }
   integer = input;
   while ( integer > 0 ) {
      check = input % 10;
      input = integer / 10;
      switch ( check ) {
         case 2: monitor | ( 2 *        1 ); break;
         case 3: monitor | ( 2 *       10 ); break;
         case 4: monitor | ( 2 *      100 ); break;
         case 5: monitor | ( 2 *     1000 ); break;
         case 6: monitor | ( 2 *    10000 ); break;
         case 7: monitor | ( 2 *   100000 ); break;
         case 8: monitor | ( 2 *  1000000 ); break;
         case 9: monitor | ( 2 * 10000000 ); break;
      }
   }
   for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
      if( i == 0 ) {
         power = 1;
      }
      else {
         for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
            power *= 10;
         }
      }
   }
   while ( k < 7 ) {
```

Comment: It seems cruel to set you that as an exercise before you've learned about arrays.  The code you've shown is incomplete.  Your code will need to handle 43556 (which covers HELLO amongst other possibilities) — that is, digits can be repeated.

Comment: Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Answer (score 1):

[A small book, a must have.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5Gl6fAWcS-_UUp2ZW5jXzdKcVU/view)

This code works as desired:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void combinaisons( const char * input[], size_t index, size_t count, char * str ) {
   const char * group = input[index];
   for( size_t i = 0, len = strlen( group ); i < len; ++i ) {
      str[index] = group[i];
      if( index+1 < count ) {
         combinaisons( input, index+1, count, str );
      }
      else {
         printf( "%s\n", str );
      }
   }
   str[index] = '\0';
}

int main() {
   const char * groups[] = {
      "ABC", /* 2 */
      "DEF", /* 3 */
      "GHI", /* 4 */
      "JKL", /* 5 */
      "MNO", /* 6 */
      "PQRS",/* 7 */
      "TUV", /* 8 */
      "WXYZ",/* 9 */
   };
   const char * input[100];
   size_t count = 0;
   char c;
   while(( c = getchar()) > 20 && count < 100 ) {
      if( c >= '2' || c <= '9' ) {
         input[count++] = groups[c-'2'];
      }
   }
   char str[100] = "";
   combinaisons( input, 0, count, str );
   return 0;
}
```

Execution trace:

```
246
AGM
AGN
AGO
AHM
AHN
AHO
AIM
AIN
AIO
BGM
BGN
BGO
BHM
BHN
BHO
BIM
BIN
BIO
CGM
CGN
CGO
CHM
CHN
CHO
CIM
CIN
CIO
```

Some explanations:

`groups` is an array of string (i.e. const char *). It can be indexed by the char, for example '2' as index 0 with c-'2'.

`input` store the selected groups, with '246', input contains `{"ABC","GHI","MNO"}`.

`str` is a string built from the letters picked into `input`, at index 0: A, B or C, at index 1: G, H or I, and so on.

The recursion is used to apply the same treatment on different index of `str` from different group extracted from `input`. The recursion terminates when no remaining group exist, when all the group from input are consumed. An important instruction is the last of `combinaisons`: `str[index] = '\0';`, it truncate the string by removing the last char added, because the recursion backtrack. I suggest to execute this code step by step with a debugger and to observe how `str` is filled.

`c = getchar()` read a single character from standard input, [see documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar).

The condition `> 20` is used to detect any non printable character, as cr to end the `while` loop.

`size_t` is the type of `count`, `count` is incremented each time a number is read from stdin with the instruction `input[count++]` which means *use count to index input array then increment it*, it's a post incrementation. The first index is zero.

Comment: not sure if dumping code on him helps him

Comment: An example of data constants usage and a short recursive function may be a starting point of questions and exchanges...

Comment: If the OP doesn't understand arrays yet, they probably haven't covered recursion either and this might be a bit advanced — but it does seem to work.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply, but thanks for your help! However, there's lots I don't understand about your code. Firstly, does c = getchar () get each number from input? And why do you have the condition to be greater than 20? And does size_t automatically count how many numbers there are in the input?

Comment: Also, why index[count++] instead of index[count]? Don't you want index to start from 0 instead of 1?